# How To Concatenate MongoDB Queries

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native, mongoskin

I am using the `find()` in `mongodb` with `mongoskin`

I am trying to grab two collections.

```
/* GET drawingList */
router.get('/drawinglist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('drawingList').find().toArray(function (err, items) {
        res.json(items);
    });
});

// GET drawingQty
router.get('/drawinglist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('drawingQty').find().toArray(function (err, items) {
        res.json(items);
    });
});
```

I try and merge them together like this,

```
router.get('/drawinglist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
        db.collection('drawingList').find().toArray(function (err, items) 
            db.collection('drawingQty').find().toArray(function (err, items)  {
                res.json(items);
    });
});
```

But the program wont run.
What is the correct way to concatenate this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to send both the results?

Comment: I am finding the results and pushing to a array as json. From what I read it is best to just make two separate queries. Which I did.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a JavaScript problem than a mongoDB one. In your example only the result of the second query will be returned, because you use the same `items` variable within the two callbacks. The second will overwrite the first.

This should give you a hint, what to do:

```
router.get( '/drawinglist', function( req, res ) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection( 'drawingList' ).find().toArray( function( err, items ) {
        db.collection( 'drawingQty' ).find().toArray( function( err, items2 )  {
            var items3 = items.concat( items2 ); // or however you want to "merge"
            res.json( items3 );
        });
    });
});
```